# JavaScript:: Is innerText safe to use?

Tags: javascript, html, innertext

I have found that script :

```
<div id="hezi-gangina"></div>

<script>
 if(document.all)
 {
    document.getElementById('hezi-gangina').innerText="This line was created via innerText";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('hezi-gangina').textContent="This line was created via textContent";
}
 </script>
```

Which makes me realize that innerText is not safe to use (...or am I wrong here)?

Which brings out 2 questions :

1. Why should I use `innerText` anyways if it's not going to work properly on all browsers (unless the benefit of `innerText` is...) ?
2. Is `textContent` is safe to use and would work in every scenario ?

Comment: Where you say `safe` do you mean, cross-browser compatible? If so, what browsers are you targeting?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP safe = cross-browser compatible. That ridiculous that you need to have several versions for each browser.